# how to save an activity to disk and reload it when restart it

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an myApp, which first starts ActivityA, then ActivityA start ActivityB. ActivityB is quite complex which holds 3 tabs.

I wrote another killApp to call killbackgroundprocess to kill my app to simulate system out of resource to recycle some apps.

After clicking home button, then running my killApp to kill my app, then start myApp again. I saw a white background panel for a while then ActivityB is repainted.

My understanding is that when clicking home button, myApp's activities are stored to disk, when restart it, ActivityB is on the top of the activity stack, so its onCreate is called again. Because ActivityB requires some time to init its content, so I saw a white background for a while before the whole activity is ready.

My question is:
1. If the app is started first time, there is no such white background issue, is it because during App starts, android system will load all resources into memory, so when ActivityB is created, it doesn't need to wait for resources to be loaded? 
2. How to solve the above white background issue? My idea is to save the whole activity to disk, such as serialize the whole activity object to a disk, then when onCreate is called again, de-serialize it. But I am not sure how to implement it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: First, you didn't have to write another app to kill your app. You can simply shell in and kill the app's process. Also note that Jelly Bean has a bunch of handy dev tools built in, including "Don't keep activities." Enable that (settings, developer options) if you want to see how each activity deals with state when killed. Beyond all that though, check out the docs on the Activity lifecyle that noisyass2 noted (your "understanding" of activities being stored to disk when you click home is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading more on Activities' LifeCycle.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks

Comment: from what i understood, you are doing some heavy stuff on the OnCreate() of your activityB. this causes the 'white background' thing. because it takes time to load all that. you can try and use OnPause() and OnResume() for serializing/saving so it does not affect the layout

Comment: Ya, you are right. OnCreate did a lot of stuff. But why if the app is started from new, there is no such issue. So comes my first question. thanks.

Comment: isnt it because when your app starts from new, it loads activityA and not activityB?

Comment: Once activityA is created, it creates ActivityB immediately. So if activityB requires that much time, the background issue should also happen with starting from new. So my guess is that there is some pre-fetch operation during app starting from new.